# Gradle doesn't find dependency when using localhost repository

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, localhost

Basically I have a library that I have generated with mavenPublish. I've been using this dependency at local level (.m2 & specific local path directory)
Now I'm planning to host it on my local repository (HTTP://localhost:8080/repository)

For some reason, gradle can't find the dependency in localhost, although I click on the link where it can't find it and it downloads automatically. So the file is there and I'm able to download it.

Do you know what could I be missing so gradle doesn't download the dependency when using a localhost?

UPDATE: I have hosted in my own github.io and it's working fine, what's wrong with localhost!? Is it a problem permission with Intellij!?